# How to loop between documents of a collection in firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to loop between documents of a collection in the firebase firestore? I have a collection which contains multiple documents with random IDs, and I want to get all these documents and display them.

What I mean is that if I had 10 documents, I want to loop between them and show each document data on the page, like when we use the **for** loop:

```
let i;

for (i = 0; i < doc /* 10 */; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += // document data
}
```

It will be fine if there is a way to make it without using the **for** loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase documentation has a pretty good example of [reading all documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection). The exact syntax depends on the SDK version you use, so I recommend starting with the examples there and then tuning them to your needs.